# Angular JS : Filter from 2 scope

Tags: angularjs, filter, scope

I have 2 scope. I want to find based on  the id of the scope "country", the country's name.

How can I print "France" for John, in this example.

```
$scope.country = [
{id:"1",name:"France"},
{id:"2",name:"Spain"}

];

$scope.people = [
{name:"John",country:"1"},
{name:"Ben",country:"2"}

]
```

I tried :

```
<tr ng-repeat="k in people">
<td>{{k.name}}</td>
<td>{{country | filter : {"id" : k.country } }}</td>

</tr>
```

I dont know if I am doit it wrong or not, but I can only get the array, not the field name of the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can set filter up this way:

```
<td>{{(country | filter : {"id" : k.country })[0].name }}</td>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xoYZyFRF6ylQpCPmEbw1?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: That's just great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "France"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Spain"
    }

  ];

  $scope.people = [{
      name: "John",
      country: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "Ben",
      country: "2"
    }

  ]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="k in people">
        <td>{{k.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="c in country | filter:{id:k.country}">{{c.name}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the smartest of the answers imo because it handles the case where there is no corresponding country

Comment: That's really smart.

Comment: @CameronRodriguez not really because there will be a missing `<td>` if  filter returns empty array.

Comment: Agreed, it shouldn't be on the td, it should be inside it so that it will show regardless. I meant it won't throw an exception

Comment: @CameronRodriguez angular catches exceptions in expressions....won't get thrown. Can prove this in my plunker example by removing country or changing id

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, generally speaking, if you want to share or access data between different scopes, you have to use the `rootScope`, but I recommend you to always use `services` if you need to share some data between scopes.

So I think it's a matter of application design not how to implement this requirement in AngularJS.

Hope this could help you